# Recursive concurrency

Tags: java, recursion, concurrency

I have the following function, in pseudo-code:

```
Result calc(Data data) {
  if (data.isFinal()) {
    return new Result(data); // This is the actual lengthy calculation
  } else {
    List<Result> results = new ArrayList<Result>();
    for (int i=0; i<data.numOfSubTasks(); ++i) {
      results.add(calc(data.subTask(i));
    }
    return new Result(results); // merge all results in to a single result
  }
}
```

I want to parallelize it, using a fixed number of threads.

My first attempt was:

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numOfThreads);

Result calc(Data data) {
  if (data.isFinal()) {
    return new Result(data); // This is the actual lengthy calculation
  } else {
    List<Result> results = new ArrayList<Result>();
    List<Callable<Void>> callables = new ArrayList<Callable<Void>>();
    for (int i=0; i<data.numOfSubTasks(); ++i) {
      callables.add(new Callable<Void>() {
        public Void call() {
         results.add(calc(data.subTask(i));
        }
      });
    }
    executorService.invokeAll(callables);  // wait for all sub-tasks to complete
    return new Result(results); // merge all results in to a single result
  }
}
```

However, this quickly got stuck in a deadlock, because, while the top recursion level waits for all threads to finish, the inner levels also wait for threads to become available...

How can I efficiently parallelize my program without deadlocks?

Comment: We don't see any synchronizations in your code, so we can't help you finding the deadlock. The code provided has nothing to do with deadlocks.

Comment: its maybe just, that numOfThreads is less than callables.size()? You should ensure in your implementation, that you have more threads than callables (down the tree) ..

Comment: @cybye only if they depend on each other, isn't it so?

Comment: they do, cause level1 is still active and allocated, when level2 is filled .. so level1 consumes a thread until all other levels finish .. aso.

Comment: Recursive Concurrency sounds like you want ForkJoinTask/Pool http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/forkjoin.html

Comment: @ATrubka the synchronization is in "executorService.invokeAll", which waits for all threads to complete.

Comment: @cybye yes, but I do want to limit the number of threads. Without recursion this works fine - when there are not enough threads, the tasks just wait for threads to become available.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is a general design problem when using ThreadPoolExecutor for tasks with dependencies.

I see two options:

1) Make sure to submit tasks in a bottom-up order, so that you never have a running task that depends on a task which didn't start yet.

2) Use the "direct handoff" strategy (See [ThreadPoolExecutor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) documentation):

```
ThreadPoolExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(poolSize, poolSize, 0, TimeUnit.SECONDS, new SynchronousQueue<Runnable>());
executor.setRejectedExecutionHandler(new CallerRunsPolicy());
```

The idea is using a synchronous queue so that tasks never wait in a real queue. The rejection handler takes care of tasks which don't have an available thread to run on. With this particular handler, the submitter thread runs the rejected tasks.

This executor configuration guarantees that tasks are never rejected, and that you never have deadlocks due to inter-task dependencies.

Comment: with 2) don't you run into the problem, that all the pool is filled with dump organization and all the heavy work will be done by the caller?

Comment: @cybye: The "caller" in this case is a thread from the pool, or actually many of them. So instead of waiting for their dependencies, they actually process the data.

Comment: Another thing that can be considered is the Fork/Join framework

Answer (score 0):

you should split your approach in two phases:

1. create all the tree down until data.isFinal() == true
2. recursively collect the results (only possible if the merging does not produce other operations/calls)

To do that, you can use `[Futures][1]` to make the results async. Means all results of calc will be of type Future[Result].

Immediately returning a Future will free the current thread and give space for the processing of others. With the collection of the Results (new Result(results)) you should wait for all results to be ready (ScatterGather-Pattern, you can use a semaphore to wait for all results). The collection itself will be walking a tree and checking (or waiting for the results to arrive) will happen in a single thread.

Overall you build a tree of Futures, that is used to collect the results and perform only the "expensive" operations in the threadpool.