# Waiting for another thread in executorservice scenario

Tags: java, multithreading

Suppose there are three threads created using executor service and now I want that t2 would start running after t1 and t3 would start running after t2. how to achieve this kind of scenario in case of thread pool?

If it would have any normal thread creating using thread.start(). I could have waited using join() method. But how to handle above scenario?

Comment: Why you need multithreading here ,if you want sequential behavior

Comment: Please see topic discussed [here][1]

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2153663/controlling-task-execution-order-with-executorservice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thread t1,t2 and t3 can implement callable interface and from the call method you can return some value.
Based on the return value, after t1 returns, you can initiate t2 and similarly for t3.

"Callable" is the answer for it

Comment: So, apart from callable any other way?

Comment: Callable was introduced for that purpose only in Java. Any issues in using Callable ?

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing the notion of threads and what is executed on a thread. It doesn't matter when a thread "starts" in a thread pool but when execution of your processing begins or continues. So the better statement is that you have 3 `Callables` or `Runnables` and you need one of the to wait for the other two before continuing. This is done using a [CountDownLatch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html). Create a shared latch with a count of 2. 2 of the `Callables` will call [countDown()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html#countDown%28%29) on the latch, the one that should wait will call [await()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html#await%28%29) (possibly with a timeout).

Answer (score 0):

Jobs submitted to an ExecutorService must be mutually independent. If you try to establish dependencies by waiting on Semaphores, CountDownLatches or similar, you run the risk of blocking the whole Service, when all available worker threads execute jobs that wait for a jobs that has been submitted, but is behind the current jobs in the queue. You want to make sure you have more workers than possible blocking jobs. In most cases, it is better to use more than one ExecutorService and submit each job of a dependent group to a different Service.

Answer (score 0):

A few options:

1. If this is the only scenario you have to deal with (t1->t2->t3), don't use a thread pool. Run the three tasks sequentially.
2. Use some inter-thread notification mechanism (e.g. BlockingQueue, CountDownLatch). This requires your tasks to hold a shared reference to the synchronization instrument you choose.
3. Wrap any dependence sequence with a new runnable/callable to be submitted as a single task. This approach is simple, but won't deal correctly with non-linear dependency topologies.
4. Every task that depends on another task should submit the other task for execution, and wait for its completion. This is a generic approach for thread pools with dependencies, but it requires a careful tuning to avoid possible deadlocks (running tasks may wait for tasks which don't have an available thread to run on. See my response [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15084302/recursive-concurrency/15084851#15084851) for a simple solution).